# Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x30000008) issue generated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an issue running an app on  a simulator.
The problem:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurring  at objc_msgSend in Thread 1.

Screenshot :

[image]

In my Application, I have multiple `ViewController`. when I click on back button of `UINavigationBar` then this type of issue is generated, I can't explain my problem because all the functionality works properly.

Example :-

1 - `fitstVController` (work properly)

=> it have UITableView, when I click on specific row then it will go on another UIViewController (SecoundViewController)

2 - `SecoundViewController` (work properly)

=> it have UITableView and UIActionSheet. when I select button of UiActionSheet then another UIViewController (ThirdViewController) is open

3 - `ThirdViewController` (work properly)

=> it have UITableView and multiple UIPickerView. But HERE IS PROBLEM THAT I CAN'T GO BACK    AT PREVIOUS UIViewController (SecoundViewController).
=> when i do that then  **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x30000008)** issue generated.

Comment: Show us the code where you perform the transition from the first to second view controller, where you go from second to third controller, and how you "go back" to the previous controller. Are you doing `pushViewController` and `popViewControllerAnimated`? Or are you doing `presentViewController` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated`? Also, make sure you turn on zombies if you haven't already.

Comment: @Rob - first i would like to thanks to you for trying to help me .        i am go bake to the previous controller by using `pushViewController`. in short i use UINavigationController.

Comment: Great, then show us the code where you invoke `pushViewController` and where you `popViewControllerAnimated`. Also, [enable zombies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html).

Comment: In Thirdviewcontroller, Try to comment every line where release of object in your Thirdviewcontroller.m one bye one.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint - this will help you to track down the source of the problem. http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2011/04/18/xcode-4-exception-breakpoint/ shows how to do this.

Comment: @AmitPatel There's nothing obviously wrong here (though stylistically I'd encourage you to start variable and property names with lowercase letter ... but that has no impact on the issue you're experiencing). But you're pushing the views correctly, so everything is good there. I assume you're just doing a simple `popViewControllerAnimated` to pop back? I think you should follow TimD's advice on exception breakpoints as well as turning on zombies. See if you can identify the precise source of the exception. Having us pour through non-ARC code won't be productive.

Comment: @ Rob & @ TimD thanks for advice..i use breakpoints. and i found that in    ThirdViewController i have 12 section in tableView and my section start with 11 number of section and after section number 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, and 10 so, how can i start my section with number 0 ?

Comment: @AmitPatel I don't understand the question. When you have 12 sections, the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol will automatically number them 0 through 11, where 0 is the first one. I'd suggest you (a) close this question by accepting an answer so it doesn't say open (if TimD posts an answer, you should accept his answer); (b) post a new question with your tableview question showing relevant snippets of how you're populating and using the data behind your tableview. Make sure to note the line of code that is generating the exception.

Comment: @TimD I'd encourage you go ahead and post your exception breakpoint comment as an answer so that Amit can accept your answer, close this question, and create a new question that focuses on the tableview problem that he's having. If nothing else, I'd like to give you an up arrow for that answer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In short, this type of problem occurs when you release the memory assigned to an object that has been already released. Most likely, this type of issue is generated when you go back to your previous `UIViewController` (or other cases).

And also, I suggest reading the following link for a more thorough explanation:

[Hamster Emporium archive:So you crashed in objc_msgSend()](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html)

Comment: How can I prevent from this? I have similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/52679190/2725435

Answer (score 5):

Setting an exception breakpoint means that Xcode will stop execution as soon as an exception is raised.  It's not entirely foolproof, but this will usually result in the app breaking on the line of code that caused the problem.

That makes it a LOT easier to track down the source of the problem - although the stack trace is the definitive way of diagnosing issues, it's often far too detailed to be of much use (especially if like me you're not a compiler expert.)

To set this up, click on the `Breakpoints` symbol in the Navigator panel and click the `+` button at the bottom. Then select `Add Exception Breakpoint`, and `Objective-C` from the List of choices.

Comment: thanks for advice of Breakpoints i found many question that i dont know. ;( but my problem is not solve :( okay but your try is best so i would like to thank you for try to help me :)

Comment: As @Rob shown i ask question related to UITableView section that `How can i start my UITableView section with number 0 when i have multiple sections?` so, please check it :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

As @TimD has rightly pointed out, you can set an [exception breakpoint](http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2011/04/18/xcode-4-exception-breakpoint/) and it will highlight the offending line of code (rather than trying to decipher the assembler or manually trying to identify where the problem is). And, as always, when diagnosing these sorts of memory issues, you should always [enable zombies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html). Finally, especially important in non-ARC code, you should run your code through the [static analyzer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Analyze/Analyze.html) as many memory related problems can be identified there. You should always make sure you have zero warnings from the static analyzer as it invariably points out critical programming errors.

Comment: As you shown , i ask question related to UITableView section that `How can i start my UITableView section with number 0 when i have multiple sections?` so, please check it :) thanks –

Comment: Great, I'll check [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455094/how-can-i-start-my-uitableview-section-with-number-0-when-i-have-multiple-sectio) out.