# releasing memory that has already been released

Tags: objective-c

The main method below is supposed to call `BNRItem randomItem` multiple times, but XCode is stopping on this line

```
 NSString *randomName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                                [randomAdjectiveList objectAtIndex: adjectiveIndex],
                                [randomNounList objectAtIndex: nounIndex]];
```

with the error

```
Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x18)
```

I've looked up this error on SO (for example, here [Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x30000008) issue generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437605/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x30000008-issue-generated)) but can't figure out why this problem is happening. That answer says,

```
this type of problem occurs when you release the memory assigned to an object that has been already released.
```

However, I don't see how that is happening. Can you explain...

main

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
     NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
            BNRItem *p = [BNRItem randomItem];
            [items addObject:p];

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++){
            NSLog(@" %@", [items objectAtIndex:i]);
        }


        items = nil;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

BNRItem.m

```
+(id)randomItem
{
    NSArray *randomAdjectiveList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Dumb", @"Hairy", @"Boring", nil];
    NSLog(@" %@", randomAdjectiveList);
    NSArray *randomNounList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Car", @"Bar", "toy", nil];


    NSInteger adjectiveIndex = arc4random() % [randomAdjectiveList count];
    NSInteger nounIndex = arc4random() % [randomNounList count];


    NSString *randomName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                            [randomAdjectiveList objectAtIndex: adjectiveIndex],
                            [randomNounList objectAtIndex: nounIndex]];

    int randomValue = arc4random() % 100;

    NSString *randomSerialNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c %c %c %c %c",
                                    'O' + arc4random() % 100,
                                    'A' + arc4random() % 100,
                                    '0' + arc4random() % 100,
                                    'A' + arc4random() % 50,
                                    'O' + arc4random() % 25];
    BNRItem *newItem = [[ self alloc] initWithItemName:randomName valueInDollars:randomValue serialNumber:randomSerialNumber];

    return newItem;


}
```

Comment: the error message is saying you trying to access memory at address `0x18`, which is not valid. it is probably not caused by over-release object

Comment: Finding the error, or at least localizing it will be a lot easier if you create each of the arguments to `NSString adjective = randomAdjectiveList[adjectiveIndex];
NSString noun = randomNounList[nounIndex];
NSString *randomName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", adjective, noun];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haha! I have fallen to this error as well before. The problem is with your

```
    NSArray *randomNounList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Car", @"Bar", "toy", nil];
```

There should be an @ symbol before "toy". You are doing initWithObject using a standard c string (which is not an object)