# How to go back to previous controller and refreshing that controller after saving

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table view inside a view controller. When i want to add something to my tableview i press the add-button and i go to a detail view controller where i have a save button. Now I want to go back to my tableviewcontroller and refresh it after pressing my save button.

I'm sending my data to an external database and not in the core data.

Comment: I think if you are able to put some sample code, then we will be able to help you further. From your short description, I think you might need **[self.tableView reloadData];**

Comment: Yeah i would like to add some code but it's too much code but  do you know how i go back to my previous view controller after pressing that save button

Comment: You can use popViewController: on your navigation controller

Comment: We need to know more details like, is the app for iPhone or iPad? Are you Using UINavigationController? And etc... Without that, we do not know how to help you. May be add a screen shot to show what you have done at the moment.

Comment: It's an app for iPhone. There is one UINavigationController in the application. I use a modal segue to go from my view controller with my table view to my add view controller

Comment: I wanted to post a picture but you need 10 rep. points for that

Comment: create own delegate and when you press save button reload your tableview.show some code..

Comment: You can try the delegate method like karthikeyan mentioned. Or try the code I wrote below.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using modalViewController, after you tap **Save button**, you may dismiss it and to refresh the data, you will need to Use **NSNotification** in this case.

Try the following code:-

Inside the **view controller** that contains the **tableview**,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tableReload) name:@"tableReload" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"tableReload" object:nil];
}

-(void)tableReload{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In the second view controller, IBAction for the save button

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"tableReload" object:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I would recommend delegating the dismissal back to the original ViewController, and in the completion block, calling reloadData. Rather than using NSNotification for something like this. NSNotification is more for a model object broadcasting it is updated, rather than a Controller IMO.

Comment: The save button and going back works but when it goes back to my view controller with my table view my application crashes. it gives me a Thread1 BAD ACCES CODE

Comment: @Jeff agree with you but delegate might not be too straight forward for beginner. I know NSNotification is not a good practice.

Comment: @Brent Can you paste the crash log? Do you have exceptional Breakpoint added?

Comment: The console doesn't log anything. I just get Thread 1 BAD_ACCES_CODE

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437605/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x30000008-issue-generated to see if there is anything related to your crash. May be you can learn how to Add Exception Breakpoint as well.

Comment: I tried to add the exception breakpoint, but still it doesn't show anything it just crashes