# The app always crashes when saving to UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know what is wrong:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    static let shared = UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)!

    static func set(object: Any, forKey key: String) {
    
        shared.set(object, forKey: key)
        shared.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Image of error in IDE:

[image: Image of error in IDE]

Comment: you are force unwrapping a failable initialiser that is probably returning `nil`, so you get a crash when you refer to it. You also don't need `synchronize`.  What is `SharedGroupName`

Comment: @Paulw11 I just updated the question.

Comment: Is that shared group name in your app's entitlements?

Comment: Yes, it is in entitlements.

Comment: Instead of setting `Date`, can you try setting any string. If string or Int is working, then convert date into epochTime and save in defaults

Comment: There is saved string, not Date;)

Comment: I think crash is related to something else and you are catching at wrong place.

Comment: I also think so;) But completely dont know where to catch that;)

Comment: Can you just move ` static let shared = UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)!` to the setter function. And also remove static keyword too. just give last try

Comment: `shared` would be nil only if passing the current application's bundle identifier, NSGlobalDomain, or the corresponding CFPreferences constants.

Comment: As Hello doesn't get printed, and @MehulThakkar said, this crash might be belong to some where else. Try using adding an Exceptions breakpoint and also enable the Zombie objects. Might be you caught the problem.

Comment: `SharedGroupName` Where is this one declared? @BartłomiejSemańczyk

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint before to inspect and print the expected objects? Also enable exception breakpoints.

Comment: I think I solved. my problem. I added observer for user defaults, dut didnt remove it when controller was deinitialized. That is the point

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk problem solved or not ?

Answer (score 3):

You should try omitting the static variable and just use:

```
UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)!.set(object, forKey: key)
```

It might make a difference.
Also, as said in one of the comments, "synchronize" is not needed.

Comment: No need to force unwrap here. It's bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I have recreated the same exact source code and its not crashing, I believe the crash is cause by something outside of the sample file that you gave. Can you add more code that might pass data to the extension?

Answer (score 1):

Just declare shared as optional.

```
static var shared: UserDefaults? = UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UserDefaults {

    static let shared = UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName! as String)

    static func set(object: Any, forKey key: String) {

        shared?.set(object, forKey: key)
        // shared?.synchronize()  obsolete
    }
}
```

1. unwrap SharedGroupName! as String
2. use optional "?" with shared will run your code fine

Comment: Commented the .synchronize

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure you need to use non default UserDefault and use a specific suiteName ?

If the answer is yes and the reason is that you are using a widget extension, make sure that both the main app target and the widget extension target have app group capability enabled and use the same and activated (the checkmark must be set) app group name.

If the answer is no, replace the init with suiteName and use the default initialiser.

- Force unwrapping SharedGroupName! and casting like doesn't look right to me.

`static let shared = UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName! as String)`

Can you please try to pass the string value of SharedGroupName directly?

Comment: It is solved already, I post an answer as a comment under question;)